# Q: On proof of the root test

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm reading Rudin's PMA and am a little bit confused as to his proof of the Root Test $(3.33)$ for the case where $\alpha > 1$.  The text says:

> Let $\alpha = \lim_{n\to \infty}\text{sup } \sqrt[n]{|a_{n}|}.$
>   If $\alpha > 1$, then then there is a sequence $\{n_{k}\}$ such that $$\sqrt[n_{k}]{|a_{n_{k}}|} \to \alpha$$  **Hence, $|a_{n}| > 1$ for infinitely many values of $n$, so that the condition $a_{n} \to 0$ does not hold.  Thus the series must diverge.
>   $\Box$

I don't understand the part that is starred.  Is it not only true $|a_{n_{k}}|>1$ for infinitely many $n$? Is it true for $|a_{n_{k}}|$?  We are given that the $n_{k}^{th}$ root converges to $\alpha$...

Comment: Each term of $(a_{n_k})_k$ is also a term of $(a_n)_n$.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  Are you saying $\{\{a_{n_{k}}\}_{k}\} \subset \{\{a_{n}\}_{n}\}$?

Comment: As sets, yes. $(a_{n_k})$ is a subsequence of $(a_n)$.  The former sequence is indexed by $k$, $a_{n_1}$, $a_{n_2}$, and so on ($n_1$ is some integer, $n_2$ is some integer greater than $n_1$). In your post $|a_{n_k}|>1$ for infinitely many $k$ (not infinitely many $n$ as you wrote). But these $n_k$ are integers and $a_{n_k}$ is just some term of $(a_n)$. I hope this helps...

Comment: Yes, thanks for the comments and pointing out the notation mistake.  Then the notation $(a_{n_{k}})_{k}$ is saying we are indexing by $k$.  Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the $n_k$ are an indexing of a *subsequence* of the original sequence. Since all terms in the tail of the subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}_k$ are greater than $1$ (because their $n_k$th roots are greater than $1$), there are arbitrarily many terms in the original sequence $\{a_n\}_n$ that are greater than $1$. That is to say, for any $N$, there will be an $n \ge N$ such that $a_n>1$. [This is *not* saying that after a certain point in the original sequence, all terms are greater than $1$.] But this is enough to make $a_n\to 0$ an impossibility.

Comment: Great,  thank you for the answer!